# How to batch transform tensors in a cnn?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-classification

(EDIT: Added the whole code)I am trying to run the following:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
from torchvision import datasets, transforms, models
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
from torchinfo import summary
from tqdm import tqdm


data_path = 'img\chest_xray' #(https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tolgadincer/labeled-chest-xray-images)

train_transform = transforms.Compose([
 transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ColorJitter(brightness=0.10, contrast=0.1, saturation=0.10, hue=0.1),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomRotation(10),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])

test_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize(224),
    transforms.CenterCrop(224),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                         [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])])
train_data = datasets.ImageFolder(
    os.path.join(data_path, 'train'), transform=train_transform
    )
test_data = datasets.ImageFolder(
    os.path.join(data_path, 'test'), transform=test_transform
    )

train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True)
class_names =  train_data.classes
print(class_names)
print(f'Number of train images: {len(train_data)}')
print(f'Number of test images: {len(test_data)}')

class Net(nn.Module):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()

        #INPUT BLOCK
        self.convblock1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=3, out_channels=8, kernel_size=(3,3),padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(4),
        )
        self.pool11 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)

        # CONVOLUTION BLOCK
        self.convblock2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=8, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(3,3),padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        )
        self.pool22 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)

        # TRANSITION BLOCK
        self.convblock3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=16, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(1,1), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
        )
        self.pool33 = nn.MaxPool2d(2,2)

        # CONVOLUTION BLOCK
        self.convblock4 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=10, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
        )
        self.convblock5 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=10, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(1,1), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
        )
        self.convblock6 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=32, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(1,1), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
        )
        self.convblock7 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=10, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
        )
        self.convblock8 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=10, out_channels=32, kernel_size=(1,1), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
        )
        self.convblock9 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=32, out_channels=10, kernel_size=(1,1), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(10),
        )
        self.convblock10 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=10, out_channels=14, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(14),
        )
        self.convblock11 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=14, out_channels=16, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=0, bias=False),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
        )

        # OUTPUT BLOCK
        self.gap = nn.Sequential(
            nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=4)
        )
        self.convblockout = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(
            in_channels=16, out_channels=2, kernel_size=(4,4), padding=0, bias=False),
        )

    def forward(self,x):
        x = self.convblock1(x)
        x = self.pool11(x)
        x = self.convblock2(x)
        x = self.pool22(x)
        x = self.convblock3(x)
        x = self.pool33(x)
        x = self.convblock4(x)
        x = self.convblock5(x)
        x = self.convblock6(x)
        x = self.convblock7(x)
        x = self.convblock8(x)
        x = self.convblock9(x)
        x = self.convblock10(x)
        x = self.convblock11(x)
        x = self.gap(x)
        x = self.convblockout(x)

        x = x.view(-1,2)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=-1)

use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device('cuda' if use_cuda else 'cpu')
print(f'Avaliable processor: {device}')
model = Net().to(device)
summary(model, input_size=(3,224,224), col_names=('output_size', 'num_params'))

train_losses = []
test_losses = []
train_acc = []
test_acc = []

def train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch):
    model.train()
    pbar = tqdm(train_loader)

    correct = 0
    proccessed = 0

    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(pbar):
        # Get data.
        data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)

        # Initialization of gradient.
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Prediction on data.
        y_pred = model(data)

        # Calculate the loss, given the prediction. (Cost function).
        loss = F.nll_loss(y_pred, target)
        train_losses.append(loss)

        # Backpropagation.
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Track the training loss and accuracy.
        pred = y_pred.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
        correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
        proccessed += len(data)

        pbar.set_description(
            desc=f'Loss={loss.item()} '
                 f'Batch_id={batch_idx} '
                 f'Accuracy={100*correct/proccessed:.2f}'
    )

        train_acc.append(100*correct/proccessed)

def test(model, device, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data, target in test_loader:
            data, target = data.to(device), target.to(device)
            output = model(data)
            test_loss += F.nll_loss(output, target, reduction='sum').item()
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            correct += pred.eq(target.view_as(pred)).sum().item()
    
    test_loss /= len(test_loader.dataset)
    test_losses.append(test_loss)

    print(
    f'\nTest set: '
    f'Average loss: {test_loss:.4f}, '
    f'Accuracy: {correct}/{len(test_loader.dataset)} '
    f'({100. * correct / len(test_loader.dataset):.2f}%)\n'
)
    test_acc.append(100.*correct/len(test_loader.dataset))

model = Net().to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
scheduler = StepLR(optimizer, step_size=6, gamma=0.5)

EPOCHS = 15
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    print("EPOCH:", epoch)
    train(model, device, train_loader, optimizer, epoch)
    scheduler.step()
    print('current Learning Rate: ', optimizer.state_dict()['param_groups'][0]['lr'])
    test(model, device, test_loader)
```

My first run was successful because `nn.BarchNorm2d()` was disabled. Now that I enabled it I am getting the following error: `Failed to run torchinfo. See above stack traces for more details. Executed layers up to: [Conv2d: 2, ReLU: 2]` and `ValueError: expected 4D input (got 3D input)`. From what I understand, during the transform.ToTensor() the input images (3channels,224H,224W) are being converted to Pytorch tensors. `nn.BatchNorm2d()` is trying to normalize a 4D tensor but is receiving a 3D one. How would I alter transforms so the tensors are 4D (in batches)? I read about `.unsqueeze` but all the examples are on single tensors.

Comment: Please share the code you use for training and perhaps some sample data as well. Otherwise it's hard to recreate your issue

Comment: Edited upon request.

Answer (score 0):

The model expects a batch of images as a 4D tensor of size `(batch_size, channels, height, width)`. If you are passing a single image, you need to add the batch dimension. You can do this with `x.unsqueeze(0)` or `x[None]`.

That said, you should check what is happening in your dataloader and figure out why it is producing incorrect tensors.

Comment: The `DataLoader` uses `transforms.ToTensor()`. From what I read in the documentation: "Converts a PIL Image or numpy.ndarray (H x W x C)". This is a 3D tensor that doesn't include an index for batch_size.                                                      
Also:
 ```python
train_loader = DataLoader(train_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True)
test_loader = DataLoader(test_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True)
```
Clearly shows a `batch_size=16` for training, and `batch_size=1` for testing.

`Batchnorm2d()` is expecting a 4D tensor while receiving a 3D one.

Comment: So, like I mentioned, I am completely new to this and I don't really know how or where exactly to place the .unsqueeze method.